# How to identify the direction of travel for ways without "oneway" tag

Tags: openstreetmap

I am using Overpass API to download ways and nodes information for my application and I have realized that not all the ways have information related to the direction of travel.

How can I identify if the way supports direction in both sides/with line direction or against direction when no tags are attached?

Example url: https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(50.05288170227778,8.69143545627594,50.05597466228186,8.694798946380615);out%20meta;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of travel depends on the presence (and the specific value!) of the [`oneway`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway) tag. If there is no `oneway` tag present then the road is bidirectional, except for other tags implicating `oneway=yes` such as:

- `highway=motorway` or `highway=motorway_link`
- `junction=roundabout`

If neither a `oneway` tag nor any of the other mentioned tags is present then the traffic is bidirectional, i.e. `oneway=no`.